# How to check for the presence of an element in an array if this element is entered by the user? (Python)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have an array and element in it. Then I'm requiring user input and storing it in a variable.

```py
root = []



#adding class for file

class my_file:
    def __init__(self, file_name, content):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.content = content


#creating object

hello = my_file("hello", "some text")

#adding object to root array

root.append(hello)  



usrInput = input("Enter element")
```

The question is: how to check for the presence of an element in the root array if the element itself is contained in a variable?  I tried the following:

```py
if usrInput in root:
    print(root[root.index(usrInput)].content)
```

But `if usrInput in root` returns false. I think this is because usrInput is being treated as the intended element of the array and not as a variable. Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: You want the user to create some objects of `my_file`, store them in a `list`, and then search for them later?

Comment: Yes, exactly it!

Comment: Is the `my_file` class just an example, or are you actually storing folder name and the folder contents? If so, the `Path` class from the `pathlib` module should help. As far as storing all that in a `List` and searching for it later, that should be easy enough.

Comment: I'm planning to use exactly this class but with additional `self.file_type` property.

Answer (score 0):

I made the whole array iterate over and each element was compared with user input. As soon as a match was found, the access operator and the property name of the object were added to the index of the matched element

```py
i = 0
isFound = False

while isFound != True:

    if usrInput == root[i].file_name:

        print(root[i].content)

        isFound = True

    else:
        i += 1
```